# Spring boot add runtime property

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am looking for a solution where spring boot recreate new datasource when DB password is changed without restart.

spring.datasource.url=url
spring.datasource.username=usr
spring.datasource.password=passwordexample`no code`
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

I have define datasource like this. What is best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good blog on how to do this sort of thing here https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/

Basically you annotate your method that returns the datasource with @RefreshScope, change the configuration values in your externalised configuration (Spring Cloud Config server) and then trigger a refresh event for your application by calling the refresh endpoint exposed by Spring Boot actuator.

Comment: is it possible to that I create all connection pool while starting application and even if when password is changed. Previous connection still works.

Comment: That's nothing to do Spring or JDBC even really. Any code that is currently using a connection would probably still work, but you'd have to be very careful about making sure all existing connections were closed and returned to the pool before destroying that pool and creating a new one.

You'd probably need some custom code where you have a collection of data sources and mark old ones as being invalid for new connections, with requests for new connections only using the latest code.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Question which I wanted to clarify is. I create a datasource while starting my application with connection pool of 10 connection. After that if my database password gets changes. will my older connection pool still work?

Comment: Probably, but that depends on how the jdbc driver and the database interact. Should be easy enough to test :-)